# How to include custom input when creating a user who uses facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, timezone

I basically have a JS solution for finding out what timezone a user is in. I utilize facebook's login button as a way for users to login/signup.

This is what I use to determine a user's timezone: http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

example:

```
  >>> var timezone = jstz.determine_timezone();
  >>> timezone.name();
  "Europe/Berlin"
```

I'd like to include the return value of the script and set it into a database as I insert the user's info from facebook as well as setting their session.

I can't find a way to plug in custom data simultaneously with facebook's user credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you pull the timezone from the info Facebook provides abput the User? Have a look at the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/

The field is called `timezone` and contains the UTC offset.

Sample request:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Ctimezone&version=v2.0

Comment: Because what if the user changes timezones and facebook doesn't know, i want the js timezone detect script to figure it out for me. I also get the actual timezone name, instead of just an offset.

Comment: I'm sure FB derives this as well from the browser settings. Not sure why you want to keep the name, for calculations etc. it would make much more sense to keep the UTC offset imho. But well..

Comment: How would I set the user's timezone in PHP? Because all I know is using the `date_default_timezone_set()` function, which doesn't allow offset numbers, and only the actual names of the timezones.